# Apache can't reach site when I pass parameters to the page

Tags: apache, docker, http, server, apache2

I am working with [TwoRavens](https://github.com/IQSS/TwoRavens) which I deployed to Apache server on a docker container.

Now whenever I try to access the TwoRavens instance, I can do that by requesting this link: `localhost:85/dataexplore/gui.html` which works just fine and shows the page I requested.

However, when I try to pass some parameters to the page (which I should to perform some actions):

`localhost:85/dataexplore/gui.html?dfId=19&key=2d5c9180-2b8a-4ae1-bcf0-7a1f7c60847b`
Apache throws a message indicating that this site can't be reached.

Comment: can you share the configuration of your apache server? also have you used Inspector in Chrome to see what exactly is not reachable? it could be there the page returns a redirect to another page and that one is not reachable.

Comment: Do you have any of your own source code that might affect this outcome?  What debugging have you already done?

Comment: You probably get an Error 500 because the script that is supposed to execute those actions fails. I would look at the app stack rather than the server config.